# PlayFramework securesocial and Lighttpd error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, lighttpd, securesocial

I am using the SecureSocial module with PlayFramework2.  I am also using lighttpd as a proxy to enable SSL for Play Framework.  This is the problem.  When I use Google OAuth2 for login, Play Framework sends google a redirect URL of:

http://devportal.sample.com:8443/authenticate/google

because I am now forcing SSL for all communications I need to be:

https://devportal.sample.com:8443/authenticate/google

This is the redirect error from Google:

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://devportal.sample.com:8443/authenticate/google did not match a registered redirect URI

Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: Got the answer from @jalias.  See below..                                                quick test: in OAuthProvider.scala, change absoluteURL() to absoluteURL(true). Let me know if that works.

Comment: I will add the change I suggested in SecureSocial. Glad to know you were able to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I added a pull request which I think fixes issues when your Play! app using SecureSocial is behind a HTTP reverse proxy. Is working for me and I'm using Apache at the moment.

https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/pull/88

Comment: The pull request is not needed since Play has the flag XForwardedSupport that you can use to make it work behind a proxy.